# Polynomials and NSA

Tags: polynomials

I'm looking for some applications of criteria of irreducibility of integer polynomials inside and outside mathematics.

I was reading the  of [CV](http://www.math.sc.edu/~filaseta/FilasetaVita2013.pdf) Filaseta, a great researcher in this area and he has gained some grants from NSA. Then this makes me think if there are some applications of this matter to computer science.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is perhaps more appropriate in math.se.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus they send me here :)

Comment: This question is too broad for any Stack Exchange site. The fact that someone got a grant from NSA doesn't mean much: US agencies give a lot of grants in theoretical topics that don't necessarily have any known industrial applications. (Though in the case of irreducibility of integer polynomials, cryptographic applications are plausible.)